# How Does CSS Impact Key-Based Browser Scrolling?

Tags: css, scroll, keyboard

I've recently noticed a bug in both my own site, and in other major sites (most notably the Gatsby documentation page).  I suspect it's a result of a browser change, but really I have no idea; it might just be a side effect of using something new like Flexbox or CSS Grid.

The bug is simple: the `Home` key, `End` key, and `UP`/`DOWN` keys don't scroll.  The page has scrollbars, and has more content to see ... and you can 100% scroll with a mousewheel or by clicking on the scrollbars and dragging ... but somehow *something* in the CSS prevents key-based scrolling from working.

You can see the bug here: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/api-reference/.  Simply start at the top of the page, and try to use your keyboard to scroll down (even after "clicking into" the right-side part of the page).  You can't ... but mouse-based scrolling *does* continue to work.

My question is not "please debug my problem for me", but rather ... how is this even possible?  What CSS styles even have the ability to impact key-based scrolling, separate from mouse-based scrolling?

(And for the record, no, I do not have any Javascript-based `onScroll` handlers or anything messing things up on my site, and I believe neither does Gatsby's site.  Even if you use the developer tools to remove all event listeners, keyboard scrolling remains broken.)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer is "a miscalculated max-height can disable keyboard-based scrolling (but not mouse-based)".

Gatsby's site had the following CSS:

```
max-height: calc(100vh - 0px - 124px);
```

(well, it actually had several different ones inside various media queries, but that wasn't relevant).

Evidently the browser didn't like how that calculation resulted, and caused this bug(?).  Switching it to a simpler:

```
max-height: 100%;
```

corrected the issue.

Obviously this was a very specific case, but if you're having keyboard scroll issues (and not mouse scroll issues), and you're sure Javascript event listeners aren't to blame, it seems `max-height` (or possibly similar properties like `height` or `max-width`) would be the next thing to look at.